# Only keep certain part of text in Excel

Tags: excel, text, formula

I have text like below in a large number of columns, I would like to keep only the "Mixed Media" part, is that possible with any built in formulas or does it require VBA?

```
{"urls":{"web":{"discover":"http://www.x.com/discover/categories/art/mixed%20media"}},"color":16760235,"parent_id":1,"name":"**Mixed Media**","id":54,"position":6,"slug":"art/mixed media"}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("""name""",A1)+8,FIND("""id""",A1)-FIND("""name""",A1)-10)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Did the job perfectly. Sorry for asking but do you know how this would be solved as well? I only need the name of the localized name. In this case "San Juan"

{"country":"PR","urls":{"web":{"discover":"https://www.x.com/san-juan-pr","location":"https://www.x.com/locations/san-juan-pr"},"api":{"nearby_projects":"https://api.x.com/v1/discover?signature=3d&woe_id=16"}},"name":"San Juan","displayble_name":"San Juan, Puerto Rico","short_name":"San Juan, Puerto Rico","id":161685,"state":"San Juan","type":"Town","is_root":false,"slug":"san-juan-pr","localized_name":"San Juan"}

Comment: How what would be solved?  Also if this answered you question please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post now. I will mark as correct!

Comment: Just Change the titles to the one before and after respectively.